# Setting options in Apache Stanbol request

Tags: semantic-web, apache-stanbol

I am trying to learn semantic-web where I can pass the sample text.
which is normally in English.

I am using IKS project to learn.

```
http://dev.iks-project.eu:8080/engines
```

Is there a way to set that I should return enhancments only in English and
if in sample test a word e.g London is repeated 10 Times it return also in RDF contents London 10 time. Can I get Unique suggestions back?